# RDBMS mailbox store for MDA/LDA

Tags: email

I am looking for a RDBMS mailbox store solution, as an alternative to "mbox", "maildir", etc., used by Procmail, Dovecot LDA, etc.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://serverfault.com/questions/619116/rdbms-mailbox-store) was closed, being a product recommendation question was on of the reasons. Please read the [help] before posting. Reading your arrogant comments and edit descriptions, it might even be better if you don't post at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dbmail.org/

> Fast and scalable sql based email services Storage of mail messages in
>   a relational database Frontends: IMAP4, POP3, ManageSieve, LMTP
>   Backends: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and SQLite Commercial development
>   and support is also available

That's their blurb. This should be what you are looking for, also comes with tons of documentation in their wiki.

License: GPLv2